# Efficient way of creating a band (or banded) matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I'm trying to create a certain style of band(ed) matrix (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix)). The following code works, but for large `M` (~300 or so) it becomes quite slow because of the for loop. Is there a way to vectorize it/make better use of NumPy and/or SciPy? I am having trouble figuring out the mathematical operation that this corresponds to, and hence I have not succeeded thus far.

The code I have is as follows

```
def banded_matrix(M):
    phis = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, M)
    i = 0
    ham = np.zeros((int(2*M), int(2*M)))
    for phi in phis:
        ham_phi = np.array([[1, 1],
                            [1, -1]])*(1+np.cos(phi))
        array_phi = np.zeros(M)
        array_phi[i] = 1
        mat_phi = np.diag(array_phi)
        ham += np.kron(mat_phi, ham_phi)
        i += 1
    return ham
```

With `%timeit banded_matrix(M=300)` it takes about 4 seconds on my computer.

Since the code is a bit opaque, what I want to do is construct a large 2M by 2M matrix. In a sense it has M entries on it's 'width 2' diagonal, where the entries are 2x2 matrices ham_phi that depend on phi. The matrix will afterwards be diagonalized, so perhaps one could even make use of its structure/the fact that it is rather sparse to speed that up, but of that I am not sure.

If anyone has an idea where to go with this, I'd be happy to follow up on that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your matrix is diagonal by blocks, so you can use [`scipy.linalg.block_diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.block_diag.html):

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import block_diag

def banded_matrix_scipy(M):
    ham = np.array([[1, 1], [1, -1]])
    phis = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, M)
    ham_phis = ham * (1 + np.cos(phis))[:, None, None]
    return block_diag(*ham_phis)
```

Let's check that it works and is faster:

```py
b1 = banded_matrix(300)
b2 = banded_matrix_scipy(300)

np.all(b1 == b2)  # True
```

```py
>>> %timeit banded_matrix(300)
>>> %timeit banded_matrix_scipy(300)
1.51 s ± 57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1.24 ms ± 4.57 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

The obligatory `np.einsum` benchmark

```py
def banded_matrix_einsum(M):
    return np.einsum('ij, kl-> ikjl',
              np.eye(M)*(1 + np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, M))),
              np.array([[1, 1], [1, -1]])).reshape(2*M, 2*M)

banded_matrix_einsum(4)
```

Output

```py
array([[ 2. ,  2. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 2. , -2. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0.5,  0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0.5, -0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.5,  0.5,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.5, -0.5,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  2. ,  2. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  2. , -2. ]])
```

Benchmark results

[image: vs all]

```py
import perfplot

perfplot.show(
    setup = lambda M: M,
    kernels = [banded_matrix_einsum, banded_matrix_scipy, banded_matrix],
    n_range = [50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300],
    logx = False
)
```

`scipy.linalg.block_diag` vs `np.einsum` details

[image: scipy vs einsum]

```py
perfplot.show(
    setup = lambda M: M,
    kernels = [banded_matrix_einsum, banded_matrix_scipy],
    n_range = [50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400],
    logx = False
)
```

Answer (score 2):

As another way, you can use numba accelerator to speed it up with jitting. I propose an equivalent `scipy.linalg.block_diag` numba method that is based on [paime answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72706301/13394817):

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def block_diag_numba(result, ham_phis):
    for i in range(ham_phis.shape[0]):
        for j in range(ham_phis.shape[1]):
            result[i * 2,     i * 2:i * 2 + 2] = ham_phis[i, 0]
            result[i * 2 + 1, i * 2:i * 2 + 2] = ham_phis[i, 1]
    return result

def numba_(M):
    ham = np.array([[1, 1], [1, -1]])
    phis = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, M)
    ham_phis = ham * (1 + np.cos(phis))[:, None, None]
    return block_diag_numba(np.zeros((M * ham.shape[1], M * ham.shape[1])), ham_phis)
```

This method will be faster than the previous ones **at least 4-5 times for up to m=400 (us scale)**. This method can be adjust for other array shapes and improved by optimizing the code further (not using the *paime* answer) and bringing all code lines to numba function or parallelizing. I didn't go further because the *paime* answer performance seemed to be satisfiable by the OP acceptance; Just to show we can use numba to write much faster `scipy.linalg.block_diag` equivalent code:

[image]