# Scale/resize a square matrix into a larger size whilst retaining the grid structure/pattern (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

```py
arr = [[1 0 0]    # 3x3
       [0 1 0]
       [0 0 1]]

largeArr = [[1 1 0 0 0 0]   # 6x6
            [1 1 0 0 0 0]
            [0 0 1 1 0 0]
            [0 0 1 1 0 0]
            [0 0 0 0 1 1]
            [0 0 0 0 1 1]]
```

Like above, I want to retain the same 'grid' format whilst increasing the dimensions of the 2D array. How would I go about doing this? I assume the original matrix can only be scaled up by an integer `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numba` if **performance** is of importance ([similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72707961/13394817)) with no python jitting and in parallel mode if needed (this code can be written faster by some optimizations):

```
@nb.njit      # @nb.njit("int64[:, ::1](int64[:, ::1], int64)", parallel =True)
def numba_(arr, n):
    res = np.empty((arr.shape[0] * n, arr.shape[0] * n), dtype=np.int64)
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):     # for i in nb.prange(arr.shape[0])
        for j in range(arr.shape[0]):
            res[n * i: n * (i + 1), n * j: n * (j + 1)] = arr[i, j]
    return res
```

So, as an example:

```
arr = [[0 0 0 1 1]
       [0 1 1 1 1]
       [1 1 0 0 1]
       [0 0 1 0 1]
       [0 1 1 0 1]]

res (n=3):
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1]]
```

### Performances ([`perfplot`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768309/perfplot-to-compare-performance-of-several-functions-with-multiple-arguments-mo))

In my benchmarks, `numba` will be the fastest (for large `n`, parallel mode will be better), after that [BrokenBenchmark answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72765944/13394817) will be faster than `scipy.ndimage.zoom`. In the benchmarks, `f` is `arr.shape[0]` and `n` is the repeating count:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `repeat()` twice:

```py
arr.repeat(2, 0).repeat(2, 1)
```

This outputs:

```py
[[1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`scipy.ndimage.zoom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html#scipy-ndimage-zoom)

```
In [3]: arr = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])

In [4]: ndimage.zoom(arr, 2, order=0, grid_mode=True, mode="nearest")
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: Interesting. Could handle where `1` could be on other indices than the matrix diagonal e.g. `arr = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]])`?

Comment: @Ali_Sh Good point. scipy.ndimage.zoom calculates the value of the elements in the grid using spline interpolation of the elements of the input array. By default it uses `order=3`, which will calculate the value of the elements based on the cubic interpolation of the neighboring elements. However, this effect is undesirable in this question, and you can avoid it by using `order=0`, which will simply interpolate the value of the destination element based on the nearest element. I updated my answer for this use case.

Comment: I am getting problem yet for the example that I wrote in the comment above (index --> `[1, 1]` must be equal to `1` not `0`). And how can we specify how many times each value must be repeated e.g. if we need a `3*3` matrix for each value (it seems you must specify `zoom` in your answer as your previous edit i.e. `ndimage.zoom(arr, n, order=0, grid_mode=True, mode="nearest")`).

Comment: I don't know why, it works on Colab (SciPy is updated) correctly, but on my machine (SciPy is not updated to the latest version) it get wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using Pillow (fork of PIL) as follows:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
n = 3 # repeatation
im = Image.fromarray(arr)
up_im = im.resize((im.width*n, im.height*n),resample=Image.NEAREST)
up_arr = np.array(up_im)
```

Example:

```
arr = np.array(
  [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]])

res (n=3):
np.array(
  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

[image: numba vs PIL all]

[image: numba vs PIL with f=70]

numba is by far the most performant in terms of speed. As the matrix size increases, PIL takes much more time.