# Perfplot to compare performance of several functions with multiple arguments (more than one)

Tags: python, numpy, performance, perfplot

I would like to show performance of some functions by `perfplot` that uses more than one arguments, but I don't know how could I do this (I'm not familiar much with `perfplot`). One said [*broadcast all args to just x*](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot/issues/14#issuecomment-327719822), but I am confused yet how to use it. Assume we have the following functions:

```
from scipy.ndimage import zoom
import numpy as np

f = 5
n = 3
arr = np.random.random_integers(0, 1, (f, f))

def scipy_zoom(arr, n):
    return zoom(arr, n)

def numpy_rep(arr, n):
    return arr.repeat(n, 0).repeat(n, 1)
```

Both `f` and `n` changes need to be evaluated and it seems it will be better to plot them separately i.e. once `f` be constant and `n` varies and once vice-versa. I don't know how understandable it will be if the [**3D** perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot/issues/88#issuecomment-776510315) could be plotted (*this will be useful if be shown in the answers, but not the main aim of this question*).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For two arguments we can collect all benchmark timings, setting the range of *f* for *arr* size with `functools.partial` and the range of *n* within `perfplot`

```py
import perfplot
from functools import partial

res = []
for f in range(5,100,20):
    arr = np.random.randint(0, 2, (f, f))
    g = perfplot.bench(
        setup=lambda n: n,
        kernels=[partial(scipy_zoom, arr),
                 partial(numpy_rep, arr)],
        labels=['zoom','numpy'],
        n_range=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
        equality_check=False # results are not equal!
    )
    res.append(g)
```

and plot a 3D graph of 2D line plot layers.

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
cc = cycler(color=list('rg'))

for i, g in zip(range(5,100,20)[::-1],res[::-1]):  # plot from back to front
    ax.plot(g.n_range,g.timings_s.T, i, zdir='y', alpha=0.8)

plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=cc)
ax.set_xlabel('n')
ax.set_ylabel('f')
ax.set_zlabel('seconds')
ax.legend(g.labels)
plt.show()
```

Output

[image: results]